# Why the component is mounted only if I refresh the page?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying To get notififications of the logged user when the component is rendered the first time so I'm using useEffect and there the code :

```
const mountedRef = useRef(true);
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    mountedRef.current = false;
  };
}, []);

const { currentUser } = props;
useEffect(() => {
  if (currentUser) {
    NotificatioDataService.retieveNotificationByDoctorId(currentUser.id).then(
      (response) => {
        if (mountedRef.current) {
          setCount(response.data.length);
        }
      }
    );
  }
}, [currentUser]);
```

I use this function to update count variable and polulated it with the number of notifications in order to update badge content value:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  <IconButton aria-label="show 17 new notifications" color="inherit">
              <Badge badgeContent={count} color="secondary" invisible={invisible} >
                <NotificationsIcon />
              </Badge>
            </IconButton>
```

- the code provide is located in miniDrawerr component
  I pass the currentUser prop to miniDrawerr in app.js file :`

```
<Route exact path="/DoctorDrawer"
              render={(props) => <MiniDrawerr authenticated={this.state.authenticated} currentUser={this.state.currentUser} {...props} />}></Route>
```

the issue is that useEffect is executed only when I refresh the page

- I hope that the question is clear :)

Comment: The `mountedRef` looks suspicious to me, what are you using that for? I think it's causing a race condition for your code - I'd try removing that.

Comment: @gerrod I used it to test if the component is mounted or not

Comment: @gerrod I remove it but the same behavior ... the issue persist

Comment: Oh, sorry - I had misread it - yes, I can see what you're doing.

Comment: OK, I can't see anything obvious - could you reproduce an example in StackBlitz or equivalent? Have you tried stepping through or adding breakpoints? Just before the `useEffect` that does the HTTP call, try logging out what `currentUser` is, maybe it's being passed as null or undefined...

Comment: I console it outside the useEffect function an I verified that the currentUser is passed from parent to child

Comment: Then sorry, it's going to be hard to help without being able to see a reproduction of the bug. The code looks fine so there must be something else going on that we can't see based on the sample that you've provided.

Comment: Thanx I appreciate your help (^-^)